# Removed SpringCM, Can't Create Opporutunity

Tags: managed-package, skuid

I recently removed the SpringCM managed package from our sandbox. I had to remove a couple of components manually (SpringCMRestWrap), but it was uninstalled nonetheless. Since then, I haven't been able to create an opportunity (we use SKUID). See attached image. Where should I look to stop the calling of SpringCMRestWrap?

[image]

Comment: Please check if there is any component left for example check for trigger on opportunity and which classes is called by opportunity insert event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out certain ApexClasses and ApexTriggers were preventing the uninstall. Used workbench to deploy XML into production. Great guide here:

https://www.salesforceben.com/way-to-delete-apex-classes-from-production/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like an issue coming from Skuid, it appears that you still have a custom trigger named "SpringCMOpportunity" in your org which is running some logic which is looking for some functionality that SpringCM provided which no longer exists. You may need to adjust the logic for this trigger to no longer depend on SpringCM, or remove it entirely.

Comment: Found out it was that I needed to delete two visual force pages. However, I'm trying to delete those same pages from Production now, and I can't seem to locate them in 'Setup-->Develop --> Pages'. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Nivi Check your List View on the Pages view, you might be excluding them from the view. Also you can use Developer Console to find the pages and delete them from there, although I am not sure if you're allowed to delete pages from production using Dev Console.